# Can Linux-burned Installers boot on iMacs?

Tags: boot, mac, burning

I know a version of this question has been answered concerning Windows, but I'm looking to burn a Linux installer.iso within Ubuntu on a PC, then boot the installer on my 2006 Intel iMac. The reason for the roundabout install is that the combination of EFI Intel 5,2 iMac (plastic version) and my UWC LG M-Disc Super Multi CD/DVD writer won't recognize or boot the Mac-burned Linux installer disc. However, the writer works with a PC, booting the installer.

So, is it possible to 1: Burn a Ubuntu installer.iso from the Linux PC, then boot that disc on my old iMac?